# How to refresh or retry a specific web page using httr GET command?

Tags: r, get, timeout, httr

I need to access the same web page with different "keys" to get specific content it provides.

I have a list of keys `x` and I use the `GET` command from `httr` package to access the web page and then retrieve the information I need `y`.

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(XML)

for (i in 1:20){
    h1 = GET ( paste0("http:....categories=&query=", x[i]),timeout(10))
    par = htmlParse(file = h1)

    y[i]=xpathSApply(doc = par, path = "//h3/a" , fun=xmlValue)

}
```

The problem is that timeout is often reached, and it disrupts the loop.

So I would like to refresh the web page or retry the GET command if timeout is reached, because I suspect the problem is with the internet connection of the website I am trying to access.

The way my code works, timeout breaks the loop. I need to either ignore the error and go to next iteration or retry to access the website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at `purrr::safely()`. You can wrap `GET` as such:

```
safe_GET <- purrr::safely(GET)
```

This removes the ugliness of `tryCatch()` by letting you do:

```
resp <- safe_GET("http://example.com") # you can use all legal `GET` params
```

And you can test `resp$result` for `NULL`. Put that into your retry loop and you're good to go.

You can see this in action by doing:

```
str(safe_GET("https://httpbin.org/delay/3", timeout(1)))
```

which will ask the httpbin service to wait 3s before responding but set an explicit timeout on the `GET` request to 1s. I wrapped it in `str()` to show the result:

```
List of 2
 $ result: NULL
 $ error :List of 2
  ..$ message: chr "Timeout was reached"
  ..$ call   : language curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
```

So, you can even check the message if you need to.

Comment: Plus one, but `try` isn't so ugly, and you can test for inherits `try-error`, avoiding a dependency (and currently two sub-dependencies)

Answer (score 5):

`http_status(h1)` can help you know where the problem lies :

```
a <- http_status(GET("http://google.com"))
a

$category
[1] "Success"

$reason
[1] "OK"

$message
[1] "Success: (200) OK"
```

and

```
b <- http_status(GET("http://google.com/blablablablaba"))
b

$category
[1] "Client error"

$reason
[1] "Not Found"

$message
[1] "Client error: (404) Not Found"
```

See this [list of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to know what the code you get means.

Moreover, `tryCatch` can help you achieve what you want :

```
tryCatch({GET(h1)}, error = function(e){print("error")})
```

Comment: tryCatch was what I needed. I don't really care what the error is, I just needed something that would prevent timeout to break the loop. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Don't forget to accept the answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

A new `httr` function `RETRY()` is also handy in these cases. `RETRY()` lets you try a call until it succeeds.

```r
httr::RETRY("GET", "http://httpbin.org/status/200")
```

Documentation - https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/RETRY.html