# Handling inconsistent test results when scraping a fluctuating website

Tags: r, rvest, testthat

Would appreciate advice from the community on how best to handle an aggravating situation.

I have a [R package](https://github.com/timtrice/rrricanes) that scrapes the National Hurricane Center archives and returns tidy storm data. The website often does not respond.

An example of this would be [this Appveyor failure](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/timtrice/rrricanes/build/1.0.122/job/4i2avb29uq31tb5t) and then the [subsequent pass](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/timtrice/rrricanes/build/1.0.125) (same branch, same commit).

Right now it has failed on four consecutive tests:

- [Build 1.0.141](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/timtrice/rrricanes/build/1.0.141/job/9itdw4pjtx2e6j74)
- [Build 1.0.142](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/timtrice/rrricanes/build/1.0.142/job/2qvuu8vypy2k4gjo)
- [Build 1.0.143](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/timtrice/rrricanes/build/1.0.143/job/2cbfkhpmw507fiml)
- [Build 1.0.144](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/timtrice/rrricanes/build/1.0.144/job/cc84qg95gnvttfcn)

Builds 1.0.141 and 1.0.143 pass the first 119 tests. Build 1.0.142 passes the first 142 tests. Build 1.0.144 fails only after 66 tests. The errors are consistent:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
>
> ```
> Timeout was reached
> ```
>
> Calls: test_check ... request_fetch -> request_fetch.write_memory ->  -> .Call

I have so many tests because there are minor discrepancies or typos in several of the products that are scraped. So, when I modify a regex pattern to accomodate these discrepancies I want to ensure I don't inadvertently break something else.

I have added options for multiple attempts, delays between requests and timeout options. Unfortunately they do not seem to have helped much, if at all.

My question to the community: can you offer advice or suggestions as a better way to handle this situation? I know it's bad form to keep tests isolated from your production environment. But I don't need all of these tests for the entire package.

How would you handle these issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with sporadically skipping the tests when you get a timeout then I'd capture the timeout like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367918/how-to-refresh-or-retry-a-specific-web-page-using-httr-get-command) and just [skip the test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/testthat/versions/0.10.0/topics/skip) if the response indicates there was a timeout. Something like:

```r
safe_GET <- purrr::safely(httr::GET)

skip_if_cant_get <- function(url) {
  resp <- safe_GET(url)

  if (is.null(resp$result)) {
    testthat::skip(paste0("Couldn't get ", url, " for testing"))
  }

  resp
}

resp <- skip_if_cant_get("http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998archive.shtml")
httr::http_status(resp$result)
#> $category
#> [1] "Success"
#> 
#> $reason
#> [1] "OK"
#> 
#> $message
#> [1] "Success: (200) OK"

# The timeout on this one will trigger the skip()
# resp <- skip_if_cant_get("http://deadbeefdeadbeef.org/")
```

This approach will stop the builds from breaking.